# Optimal way to handle a large list of Textviews

Tags: android

I have to make this in xml:

[image]

At the moment I have this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:pixlui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.neopixl.pixlui"
android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/view_general_properties"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/view_property_interior_properties"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is view_general_properties:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="12dp"
android:paddingRight="12dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/general_properties"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title_fontsize" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.66"
        android:text="@string/total_living_area" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:text="220 m²" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.66"
        android:text="@string/number_of_fronts" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:text="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.66"
        android:text="@string/number_of_accommodation_units" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:text="2" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.66"
        android:text="@string/number_of_floors" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:text="4" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.66"
        android:text="@string/condition_of_the_building" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:text="Uitstekend" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.66"
        android:text="@string/frontage_street" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:text="6m" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.66"
        android:text="@string/year" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:text="1902" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This works fine, but since I have a lot of duplicate code I was wondering if there is a better solution for this scenario.

Thanks!

Comment: You want a style, so you can give them all the same parameters and just change them once if needed.  It works very similar to CSS, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html for info.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways in which this can be improved.

Trivially, all the common style attributes for each `TextView` can be pulled out into a style. See the developer docs for [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

I'd go further, and create a separate layout resource file for one single line of your content, containing the two `TextView`s. Leave out the text values, but assign `id` values to each `TextView`.

**my_list_item.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.66" />
    <TextView
        style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in your code, manually inflate one of these for each data item, and add it to your list dynamically.

```
View item;

for ( /* each data item in my list */ ) {
    item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, containerView, true);
    TextView label = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.label);
    TextView value = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.value);
    label.setText(dataItem.label);
    value.setText(dataItem.value);
}
```

where `containerView` is the outer `LinearLayout` which holds your list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a better way. Use  `ListView` instead. If you don't know how to use `ListView` and `Adapters` do a Google around because there's thousands of tutorials and examples on it.

I can see a couple of answers suggesting to use Style, yes, those are nice suggestions, but for such a long list you'll be wasting memory and the scroll won't be smooth. A `ListView` will be much more efficient.

The details specific to your case I would suggest is:

- override [`getViewTypeCount()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount()) on your `adapter` and return `2`. That means you have two different types of views on your list. One for the titles (bold letter) and another for the item/price.
- override [`getItemViewType(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) and return `0` if it's a title position (position 0, 8, etc) and return `1` otherwise.
- then on your `getView()` on your adapter, you'll check `if(getItemViewType(position) == 0)` do the title, `else` do the item.
- The title XML will probably just a `TextView` with the proper style `bold`, size, paddings.
- The item XML will probably be a `LinearLayout` with `orientation` horizontal and the two `TextView` inside it, for the item name and for the value.
- On both items you apply the normal view recycling and view holder pattern you can find on any `ListView` tuto/example

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I would use, is to implement it using a list view with an array adapter attached to it.

There is a lot of way that you can include sub header (ALGEMENE KENMERKEN, INTERIER in your case) in the list view.

You will get advantage of the reusability in the adapter implementation.